# How to use sed to exclude a word

Tags: regex, sed, grep

I am trying to run **sed** command to display the text from a file by excluding lines starting from "**This**". I am able to perform the same operation with grep but having trouble with sed. I tried the following command :

```
sed -n '/[^This]/p' example
```

It is printing out the whole file as it is.

```
This is first line of example text
It is a text with erors.
Lots of erors.
So much erors, all these erors are making me sick.
This is a line not containing any erorrs.
This is the last line.
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2):

like this:

```
sed '/^This.*$/d' example
```

Comment: Or even, `sed '/^This/d'`.

Comment: That should be the answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to skip printing the lines that start with `This`.

```
sed -n 's/^This// ; t end; p; :end'
```

What it does is as follows:

1. Similar to your attempt it uses the `-n` option to avoid automatic printing.
2. Next it tries to substitute `This` at the beginning of the line with an empty string.
3. We need to perform the substitution only to activate the following `t` command that branches straight to the following `:end` label. The line would be discarded anyway.
4. If the substitution did not occur and therefore the `t` command was not activated, the `p` command prints the line out.

The result would be:

```
It is a text with erors.
Lots of erors.
So much erors, all these erors are making me sick.
```